# Rename medialibrary tag to media-library

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Here is my suggestion to split this tag with hyphen as its two different words.

Change tag to media-library instead of medialibrary
Couple more such as linkdatabase to link-database and linkmanager to link-manager

Answer (score 2):

Done, done, done, and a-few-more-I-found.